# How to make Google Chrome to stop automatically modify contenteditable elements HTML source?

Tags: xhtml, google-chrome, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I am using contenteditable attribute for a purpose of my own WYSIWYG editor. Most of the problems I solved myself, however one I can't figure out.

Contenteditable is acting little weird, because my editor generates XHTML code and as soon as I insert this code in contenteditable element, it modifies it to non-XHTML code, e.g.:

```
<h1>headline</h1><br />some text
```

modifies to:

```
<H1>headline</H1><BR>some text
```

There are more changes made by browser (I am using Google Chrome 7), but I think this example is good enough.

Is there a way how to change behaviour of contenteditable in Chrome, either not to touch the inserted code or to turn on "XHTML mode" ?

Comment: Are you sending the XHTML Content type?

Comment: Can't repro in older versions of Chrome - if I'm not mistaken, v7 is a beta/dev version, so it's probably just a bug. You should fill out a bug report over at the Chromium home page.

Comment: it behaves the same in older versions of Chrome as well

Answer (score 1):

Webkit is quite crappy with regards to the way that it handles contentEditable, you'll have to write a lot of code just for it.

You can look at the code existing in other editors like CKEditor and TinyMCE to see how nasty it can get.

Comment: Well, right now I am using PHP for post-processing input from my WYSIWYG editor to fix what contenteditable changes. Most of it are regex replacements, etc.. It works but I am not satisfied with this, I would like the contenteditable element to stop modifying the source code or do it in XHTML-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Serving the document with a content-type of `application/xhtml+xml` should turn on XML mode.

Comment: I've tried your advice, however, another problem shows up. Since the document is not 100% XHTML valid, Chrome instead of rendering it, it shows error message about document not beeing valid. Document is not valid, because the editor previously produced not-valid code and it will probably happen in the future too. So I can't risk, that non-valid page will result in error page to show up, users wouldn't appreciate that :-) So do you think there is no other way to turn on contenteditable XHTML mode or turn its modifying behaviour off ?